# How do I get my AIML bot to only make one response?

Tags: bots, chatbot, aiml

I'm a coding newbie programming a chatbot for entertainment purposes. I'm currently using PandoraBots as the host for it.

So as you probably know, if you type in multiple sentences to a chatbot, the default setting is for the bot to respond with the same amount of messages as sentences. This makes the bot seem less "real" than I want him to.

For example, let's say I wanted to talk about the stomachache I had.

> USER: I'm not feeling so good. Must have been something I ate. Ugh.

A real person will respond to the general idea of the phrases and likely respond with one message.

> USER: I'm not feeling so good. Must have been something I ate. Ugh.
>
> FRIEND: Lol you shouldn't have had those jalapeno poppers
>
> USER: Oh shut up.

But a bot will respond with a message for every full stop it detects.

> USER: I'm not feeling so good. Must have been something I ate. Ugh.
>
> BOT: Being sick is no fun. Get some bed rest!
>
> BOT: I like to eat cookies!
>
> BOT: Well then.
>
> USER: Now my immersion is completely lost. Thanks a lot, bot.
>
> BOT: If you're lost, pull out a map!
>
> BOT: You're welcome, my friend.

Because of some of the programming I already have in my bot, I'd like him to randomly respond to either the first sentence or last sentence only, for a more natural sounding conversation, like this:

> USER: I'm not feeling so good. Must have been something I ate. Ugh.
>
> BOT: Being sick is no fun. Get some bed rest!
>
> USER: Wow what a believable and fun interaction! Good bot!
>
> BOT: I'm glad you think I'm doing good.

Is something like this possible through Pandorabots? And if so... what's the code for it? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

This is by design, as the chatbot will not know automatically what part of the user input it should concentrate on. For example, in your input, if the bot just processed "UGH" and ignored the rest of the sentence, it wouldn't make much sense.

The only way for the bot to process the input as a single unit would be to remove the sentence-splitters from your bot's property file.